# player.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem) calls .readyToPlay twice

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avplayer

I initialize the first time

```
// viewDidLoad
player?.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem)
```

and this runs once

```
... = player?.observe(\.currentItem?.status, options: [.new, .old]) {
            
    switch (player.status) {
    case .readyToPlay:
          // start playing video
    }
}
```

I set this to nil

```
// navigationController.pushViewController ...
player?.replaceCurrentItem(with: nil)
```

I initialize it **again**

```
// on the pop back from the nav using a delegate method to reinit it
player?.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem)
```

and this runs **twice**

```
... = player?.observe(\.currentItem?.status, options: [.new, .old]) {
            
    switch (player.status) {
    case .readyToPlay:
          // start playing video
    }
}
```

Why is `.readyToPlay` getting called twice the second time (and every time thereafter with the same procedure) but only once the first time?

Comment: Because you are calling `replaceCurrentItem` twice! So of course you would observe two changes in `currentItem?.status`. Can you explain why you think otherwise?

Comment: The first time I initialize it, is in viewDidLoad. When the user pushes on a new vc I nil it out, when they come back to the vc I reinitialize it. It gets initialized at 2 separate times.